# MavenActionUtil.getMavenProject(e.getDataContext()) is Null when developing a intellij plugin

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin, intellij-plugin

I want to develop a idea intellij plugin just like "Maven Helper".  I have to get the "MavenProject" object before I can do some biz logic.  But I found the MavenProjectsManager is null (I use it in a maven project.)? Could someone give me some dev guide about this ? Thanks!

```
  public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
    Project project = e.getData(PlatformDataKeys.PROJECT);
    VirtualFile file = e.getData(PlatformDataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE);

    if (file == null || project == null) {
        return;
    }
    String fileName = file.getName();

    if (!fileName.endsWith(POM_XML)) {
        return;
    }

    final MavenProjectsManager projectsManager = MavenProjectsManager.getInstance(project);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you've added the jars of the Maven plugin to the classpath of your IntelliJ IDEA SDK and not as a separate library. Doing the latter will cause two copies of the Maven plugin classes to be loaded, which will lead to the problem that you're describing.

Comment: Thanks! I solved this with your help. I guess that if you want to get "MavenProject" or other "Maven" information in plugins, you have to do two things.
- add "maven.jar " and "maven-server-api.jar" to your Intellij IDEA SDK,
- add depends "<depends>org.jetbrains.idea.maven</depends>"  to your plugin.xml.

I guess right?